# Remote lookup using @ejb annotation

Tags: java, ejb

I have 2 servers instances of Jboss 5, each of which is deployed with two EAR's. Say Client.Ear and Server.Ear. 
Server Ear expose some ejb's. I want to inject this to ClientEar via annotation. Using JNDI lookup i did it fine and it works. But using annotation i always get  javax.naming.NamingException.
However when injecting session beans accross deployment artifacts the global JNDI name has to be used for injection and i used that also like
 @EJB(mappedName ="java:global/Server/component/ApplicationService!com.test.server.ApplicationServiceInterface")

But it seems like I am not providing the provider_url of the remote server to bound it to the client ear instance.
How could i configure jndi properties, ie provider_url, initial context properites with the annotation @ EJB?

Answer (score 6):

I found a forum post that answers your question:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/228789

In it he refers to  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance

And to accomplish the jndi lookup with the @EJB annotaion he uses

```
@EJB(lookup = "ejb:earname/modulename/BeanClass!fully.qualified.RemoteInterface")
private RemoteInterface bean;
```

Comment: Note that the remote host, port and user info have to be defined via a properties file for this to work. Place a `jboss-ejb-client.properties` file under your root source folder. An example for such a file is here: https://github.com/akquinet/jbosscc-wildfly-examples/blob/master/ejb-remote-example/ejb-remote-example-ejb-client/src/main/resources/jboss-ejb-client.properties

Answer (score 1):

`@EJB` annotation can only be used if the applications are deployed in the same sever instance. `@EJB` annotation won't work if you are trying to make cross server instance call or remote server call. So, in your case, annotation injection won't work.

**So, what are the solutions ?**

**Option 1)** Use old style *programmatic JNDI look up*

**Option 2)** Create managed bean as per `CDI (Context Dependency Injection)` and configure all the JNDI properties there. And `@inject` the `managed bean` into your client.

Comment: Many application servers support the use of the `@EJB` annotation to target remote beans, including JBoss (as per rodrigo's answer), and Glassfish.

Comment: But Rodrigo's answer doesn't show where to define the IP address of the server which is deploying the remote EJB.

Comment: @Farah: You define the IP address of the server via a properties file. In case of Jboss, you place a `jboss-ejb-client.properties` in your source root folder. For an example, see: https://github.com/akquinet/jbosscc-wildfly-examples/blob/master/ejb-remote-example/ejb-remote-example-ejb-client/src/main/resources/jboss-ejb-client.properties

Answer (score 1):

I know this little too late . Including this for further reference

You can use the portable look up String format
EJBs use RMI over IIOP and has standard mapping EJB architecture to CORBA
So you can lookup by server host and portnumber by

```
@EJB(lookup = "corbaname:iiop:example.com:3701#java:global/mycrud/mycrud-dss-ejb/InformeBean!com.myorg.ejb.InformeRemote")
```

References:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/idl/corba.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/idl/INStutorial.html

Comment: It's sounds perfectly but when I invoke the remote service I get no response and no error ever...

The only way it worked was through lookup using Abstract Factory.

Comment: With the example:


`Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "server.com");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
            return (RemoteService) ctx.lookup("com.server.package.RemoteService");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            ...;
        }`